# A better way to check semi-definite for symmetric matrix stored in scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have a very large symmetric matrix to store and manipulate in RAM (about`40,000 * 40,000`), so I use *scispy.sparse* format to store half of it, below is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
def to_sparse(W):
    tmp = np.tril(W)
    del W
    return coo_matrix(tmp)
```

Then I want to calculate the *laplacian matrix* for `W`(*the symmetric one*), according to the formula `L = D - W`, (where `D` is the diagonal matrix whose diagonals are sums over either cols or rows of `W`), according to definition of `L`, I need to check whether it's positive semi-definite(PSD) or not.

But it seems like calculating the eigenvalues of the `'L'` stored in sparse format are not equivalent to the original problem, so I have to convert `L` to dense format, and then check? **My question: is there a better way to achieve this without converting `L` back to dense matrix?**

Below is my code to generate `L` and check PSD:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
from numpy import linalg
def gen_D(W):
    # W is sparse matrix
    tmp = W.sum(axis = 0)
    tmp2 = W.sum(axis = 1).T - W.diagonal()
    return np.squeeze(np.asarray(tmp + tmp2))
def gen_laplacian(W):
    D = gen_D(W)
    return diags(D, 0).tocoo() - W
def check_PSD(L):
    origin_L = L.todense() + L.T.todense() - np.diag(L.diagonal())
    E, V = linalg.eigh(origin_L)
    return np.all(E > -1e-10)
```

I'm so sorry that I didn't check the code sample before uploading it, and now I've fixed the bugs, and below is a example:

```
W = np.random.random_integers(1, 100, size = (100, 100))
W = .5 * (W + W.T)
W = to_sparse(W)
L = gen_laplacian(W)
```

Comment: Give us a working example (with a small `W`).  There are several errors, such as using `W` after deleting it, applying `.T` to a 1d array, missing return value.  As is the code will not work.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm so sorry that I hurried to upload the code before checking it, and now I've fix the bugs

Comment: You'll get some time savings (in the math operations) by using `csr_matrix` rather than `coo`.

Comment: @hpaulj you are right, I read the documentation of `scipy.sparse` and it syas once generate a `coo_matrix` or `lil_matrix`, convert it to `csc_matrix` or `csr_matrix` will accelerate the compution. But I still wonder is there a better way to check PSD or is there any specific relationship between eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix and its triangular ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the original array already sparse (plenty of zeros), or are those just a product of `tril`?  If the later, you might not be saving space or time by using sparse code.  For example

```
def gen1(W):
    tmp = np.tril(W)
    d = tmp.sum(0)+tmp.sum(1)-tmp.diagonal()
    return np.diag(d) - tmp
```

is 8x faster than `gen_laplacian(to_sparse(W))` for this 100x100 test.

```
def check(L):
    oL = L+L.T-np.diag(L.diagonal())
    E, V = linalg.eigh(oL)
    return np.all(E > -1e-10)
```

Even `check(L.A)` is 2x faster.

But do you need to construct `orginal_L`?  It looks like `linalg.eigh(L.A)` produces the same thing, since `the calculation is done with the lower triangular part`. Not that constructing `orginal_L` takes much time.

But the crux of the testing question is whether a `sparse.linalg` function like `eigsh` produces something equivalent to `eigh`.

I don't know enough about those `eigh` functions to help - without digging further into the documentation.

Comment: Whether `original_W` is sparse or not depends on the feature extraction method on the real data set and what kind of similarity function used. I tested your code using `%timeit` and it's much, much faster than mine indeed, and this morning I've also looked up many references, which show there's no special relationship between eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix and its triangular ones, except for the `trace(L)` is equal, so seemingly there is no need to convert a no sparse symmetric matrix to sparse format. Btw, thanks a lot~:)

Comment: Btw, if `W` is not sparse, is `d = W.sum(0)` and convert `d` to `D` using `D = np.diag(d)` if necessary will faster?

Comment: I mean if I don't change `W` to `sparse.csc_matrix`, there is no need to transfer `W` to its `tril` either? Coz' I'm working on two versions now, for different original `W`

Comment: I think for real sparse original `W`, `sparse.coo_matrix(W).tocsc()` is the best way~